# Swing JDBC SQL Exception Handling

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc

I have been developing a JDBC program that uses swing and lets users interact with a database.

During development, SQL Exceptions have just been caught with a print stack trace (although they haven't happened yet - still protecting against exceptions is needed. )
How should I handle the exceptions in a user friendly way? With a dialog saying :
'Database error' ?
How much should I reveal to the user, it could be insecure to give them too many details but yet again, with none they can't fix anything or inform us of bugs.

Comment: You could log such errors, send the stack trace as a mail to your error-catching account and look into it with high priority. On the client side, you can simply display 'Error establishing connection to your account. Please try after sometime'. That buys you a little time to fix the issue.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Buying a bit of time sounds like a plan.

Comment: I'll make it an answer right away then

Comment: Each error is going to be contextual, for example, the information you present to the user because the connection failed, is going to be different from a select query (and possibly the insert/update) messages. You need to determine if it's a user error or a code error, for example, if it's the user who input an incorrect value on the query or if you're code screwed up

Comment: What we generally do at work is show a "general" message (query failed), followed by the "message" from the exception, we then have a "report" button to report the exception (just emails it) and a show/hide stack trace capabilities, because when it blows up in your own face, it's nice to be able to see it immediately

Comment: Thanks. And the message (ex.getMessage()) could never be harmful to show? I'm not especially worried about security but it's worth thinking about.

Comment: @D.Clayton Generally speaking no, but that will come down to your needs, for example, if it's a query format issue (that the user has generated), then the message might actually help them solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest making a logging system. So you log activity in the application including exceptions. Here you could make more detailed descriptions of exceptions and if you are concerned about security you can encrypt the log. When an exception occurs give the user the chance to export the log of the current session and send it to you as a error report (if encrypted you can decrypt it -> a good place to use asymmetric encryption). 
If the user can write sql statements then inform them of a syntax error. If you lost connection to the database also tell him that happened but never forward any specific information about the exception.

Comment: Thanks, any sources you could recommend for learning to use  this? Or just standard exception logging and write my own way to use it?

Comment: Just make a folder with a log file (name: date+time). Write to the file what the user is doing. <br/>
Example: 
<code>
     Thread: thread1  User pressed button1;
     Thread: thread1  Button1 action starting to execute
     Thread: thread1  Button1 action executed successfully;
     Thread: thread1  User pressed button2;
     Thread: thread1  Exception: "stack trace" /*(you can log data used in the action to make debugging easier)*/
</code>
For a quick example on encription: [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/BasicRSAexample.htm)

Comment: @D.Clayton Sorry for a lack of formatting in the comment I am new to this so still haven't learned how. :/

Comment: Thank you, that's the kind of thing I was looking for. Well answered, easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could log such errors, send the stack trace as a mail to your error-catching account and look into it with high priority. On the client side, you can simply display 'Error establishing connection to your account. Please try after sometime'. That buys you a little time to fix the issue.